# Remove the shadow on the right side of the left sideMenu in react-native-navigation v2?

Tags: react-native-navigation

How can we remove the shadow from the left sideMenu from react-native-navigation v2.
[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is not support yet, but if you want to fork or edit the implementation here is the line https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/a591fe4476ca152a336022e2570431b677f60225/lib/ios/RNNSideMenu/MMDrawerController/MMDrawerController.m#L220

```
    [self setAnimationVelocityLeft:MMDrawerDefaultAnimationVelocity];
    [self setAnimationVelocityRight:MMDrawerDefaultAnimationVelocity];

    - [self setShowsShadow:YES];
    + [self setShowsShadow:NO];
    [self setShouldStretchLeftDrawer:YES];
    [self setShouldStretchRightDrawer:YES];
```